# What can be the effects over the path itself of a gamma-ray burst traveling between two intermediate points of space-time?

Tags: waves, astrophysics, astronomy, relativity, gamma-rays

We assume that a gamma-ray burst travels from a source $S$ to a target $T$, and we consider how our gamma ray interacts with our path, when our ray travels between two intermediate points (in space-time), two points thus between those $S$ and $T$, say us $A$ and $B$. I am interested to know what the effects are, if there are any, of a gamma-ray burst travelling in transit from our intermediate points $A$ and $B$ over our path of void (empty set) itself.

My belief is that an appearance of such energy, in transit from $A$ to $B$, has a consequence on the *cells of space-time*. Is it falsifiable, or what can you say about that a gamma-ray burst travelling from intermediate points $A$ to $B$ should interact with the way (where are defined certain fields or maybe that I've called cells of space time)?

Comment: I know that a model for objects in physics is the harmonic oscillator.

Comment: Thank you very much for the improvements of my post @Cursed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validated model of cosmological data depends on [General Relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity). In GR space time is continuous, no "cells".

In this model bundles of energy , as these hypothetical gamma ray burst can be described, will distort space time at their trajectory , so molecules as the gammas are passing with velocity c, will feel a gravitational pull. If the gammas  fall on some masses, depending on sizes and energies they will melt them or turn them to gass, or if it is a star or a large planet, they will be absorbed , as happens [when they are detected](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2016AAS...22734003A) here on earth.

(One must also take into account the redshift due to the [expansion of space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang) from their creation to our present space time-moment.)

Comment: Many thanks, I am wait some days if there are more answers for this question, but your answer seems unbeatable.

Comment: I've read the article *Gamma-Ray Burst Hints of Space-Time Foam*,  by Robert Naeye from SKY & TELESCOPE (February 19, 2009). The theory of gamma ray burst is incredible.